# A Coin is thrown unti two consecutive heads come up find the expected no of tosses

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

Now I posted this question because

1)Ans in my book and many other sites was not matching

2)I would be greatful if some mathematician checks my work and tells me where I have made a mistake in my trial on this.

My attempt:
I made a recursive relation on the event that let $P_n$ be the event that I get 2 consecutive heads on the n-1th and nth toss.ie
$P_n$ is the event that I require n tosses.
*Recursive is like this*
$P_n={\frac{1}{2}}(P_{n-1}) +{\frac{1}{4}} (P_{n-2})$
General soln to this is ($a{\alpha}^{n} +b{\beta}^{n}$)***
where alpha,beta are given by finding roots to charecterisic eq $ (x^{2}-{\frac{1}{2}}(x) +{\frac{1}{4}}) =0$
Here I solved the eq and found alpha beta which are
${\frac {1+\sqrt{5}}{4}}$and ${\frac {1-\sqrt{5}}{4}}$
After this I am attaching image as I cant write my steps in this coding as it would req a lot please see the img thanks for cooperation.

[Click here for 1st img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTl4z.jpg)

And then  this
[Click here for 2nd img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBadm.jpg)

Here in *** I found **a and b** by solving the eq for $p_1$=0 and $p_2$=(1/4) after that I considerd $\alpha$ as p and $\beta$ as s the. Is solved $\sum n(p)^{n}$ by taking p common and then observing that this is the derivative of an infinite gp which can be calculated. then  I did that (as shown in the pic where I assume polynomials p and s as a substitue for alpha and beta.) And  finnaly at the end I put value of everything and that ans doesnt come as an integer and just for knowledge p and s are less than 1 that why I used diffrentiation on on infinite series sum.
With this all the power inside me faded as I receded into oblivion typing this message . Please some kind soul here help me please  By telling me what wrong I did.

Comment: Must you do it in a cumbersome way ? Or can you do it any way you like ?

Comment: I can't find another way

Comment: Not the easiest way, but should work. I do get $E\{n\}=6$ after plugging in your numbers...

Comment: Yeah nice nice thanks a lot

Comment: @ aschepler did you do it my way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we label $A$ as start, when we are waiting for the first $H$, and label $B$ when the previous toss was $H$, so if we toss a $H$ again, we have "won", ie tossed two heads in succession.

We want to know the expected number of tosses starting from $A$. The problem is that to "win" we may be shuttling between $A$ and $B$ a number of times.

With the first toss, we either get a head and are at $B$, or waste a toss and are back to $A$.This can be represented by the equation

$A = 1+ \frac12\cdot B + \frac12\cdot A$

And from $B$, one toss either gets a "win" or sends you back to $A$, ie starting again, and this can be represented as

$B = 1 + \frac12 \cdot A$

Solving these two equations yields $A = 6$

so the expected number of tosses needed to get two *consecutive* heads = $6$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126201/discussion-on-answer-by-true-blue-anil-a-coin-is-thrown-unti-two-consecutive-hea).